# Updating a column in Db2 by using a Substring of another column in the same table

Tags: sql, db2

I have a DB2 Table

```
Table A
--------
A1 | A2
```

Columns have datatype `A1 Char(50)` and `A2 Char(1)`. Now I would like to update the column **A2** with the 46th character of **A1** for 5 days history update using `Load date in Where` condition.

Comment: please provide sample data and expected output in table format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```
UPDATE table_A set A2 = substring(A1, 46, 1) WHERE ....
```